# Apache/Lion not serving site on localhost with name based virtual hosting support

Tags: php, apache, localhost

Ive configured Apache for Name-based Virtual Hosting but I can't seem to get a local site to show in my browser. Is my httpd.conf misconfigured? Here's the sanitized version:

```
#
# Use Name-based Virual Hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *.:80

#
#Set up permissions for VirtualHosts in ~/Sites
#
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# For http://localhost in the OSX default location
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thewebsite.local
    CustomLog "/Users/myusername/Sites/logs/thewebsite.local-access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "/Users/myusername/Sites/logs/thewebsite.local-error_log"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/thewebsite.local"
</VirtualHost>
```

And my etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       thewebsite.local
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the first line to be `NameVirtualHost *:80` instead of `NameVirtualHost *.:80`.
Also, add your documentRoot for `_default_` in quotes `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"` (just to be consistent across the file.)
Also try adding the Directory permissions inside the Virtual Host.

I have made the changes in the code below. Try them.

```
#
# Use Name-based Virual Hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80


# For http://localhost in the OSX default location
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thewebsite.local
    CustomLog "/Users/myusername/Sites/logs/thewebsite.local-access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "/Users/myusername/Sites/logs/thewebsite.local-error_log"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/thewebsite.local"
    <Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Quotes are only needed if there are spaces in the path, in order to disambiguate it from multiple arguments to the directive.

Comment: Agreed, I just added it to be consistent with the rest of the file.

Comment: I've implemented all of the above changes one by one, restarting apache and flushing the dns cache (for the sake of consistency) after every change to the httpd-vhosts.conf file in my ~/Sites folder and I'm still getting a 404 File Not Found when I navigate to `http://localhost/thewebsite.local`

Comment: navigate to `http://thewebsite.local` and not `http://localhost/thewebsite.local`

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end of your httpd.conf file the following line:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
```